# Delphi 2009 gives access violation error when integrated debugging is enabled

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2009

I'm pretty much at my wits end at the moment.

I am using Delphi 2009 (Update 3) on Vista (service pack 2) and without fail, if integrated debugging is enabled and I try to run a project, it will give an access violation and the project will crash out.

This happens even if I haven't even added any code to the default project template.

The only way I get around this is by disabling the integrated debugger, (then I may as well just be using a text editor and a command line compiler...)

Does anyone have any advice for this? I've been googling without much success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this combination without any problem.

Have you tried at at a clean machine (just installing delphi and try a "hello world" application?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project > Options, Compiler tab.  Uncheck Optimization, check stack frames.  This seems to be the usual advice in the faqs on Delphi debugging.  It may only apply to the earlier versions of Delphi but is worth trying.